# I have problem linking my css to html using external method of writing css

Tags: html, css

Have been trying to link my html and my css writing code using css external method, can anybody put me through please?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your HTML and CSS file are in the same forder then use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my CSS file name.CSS" type="text/CSS">
```

Comment: The question seems to be about external CSS files that may not be in the same folder as the HTML code

Answer (score -1):

1.Rename your css file to style.css and html file should be index.html
 2.put your css and html file in the same directory.
 3.write this is your css file (for test)

```
body{
 background-color:red;
```

}

4.and your html file should be like this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

5.run the index.html in your browser

Answer (score -1):

if your css file is on the same folder of the html file then the link will be in the following way.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_file_name.css">
```

if your css file is on another folder in the root directory then:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folder_name/css_file_name.css">
```

Answer (score -2):

You can inspect in chrome developer tool to and see if the external file shows 404 error (Console tab).
Alternatively, make sure the external CSS file path is correct.

Extenal CSS referencing:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
</head>
```

Hope this helps.